# Solve $2^x \cdot 3^y = 1 + 5^z$ in positive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Solve $2^x \cdot 3^y = 1 + 5^z$ in positive integers.

I think a useful idea for tackling this question is considering congruences. If we consider the equation modulo 4, we get that the RHS is congruent to 2, so $x=1.$ If $y > 1,$ the LHS is congruent to 0 modulo 9. The residues of $5^z$ modulo 9 for $z=1,2,\cdots, 6$ are $5,7,8,4,2,1$. So 5 is a primitive root modulo 9. Thus in order to have $1+5^z\equiv 0\mod 9,$ we must have $z \equiv 3\mod 6$. But then considering the equation modulo 6 or 3 doesn't seem to yield any contradiction.

Comment: $(1,1,1)$ is the only small solution (it would not surprise me if it is the only solution)

Comment: $5^{6k+3}+1$ is always divisible by $7.$ I thought to check that because $6=7-1,$ so it was the most likely common favt of the right side for those cases $z=6k+3.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That is a quite simple & straightforward solution. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%242%5Ex%20%5Ccdot%203%5Ey%20%3D%201%20%2B%205%5Ez%24&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [exponential diophantine equations marathon](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2502924p21138449) where this problem is stated as P$5$ in message #$10$ and a different (longer & more complicated than yours) solution, using the factoring of a cubic to contradict the assumption of a smallest value for $z$ being chosen, is given in message #$12$ there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $z=6k+3,$ then $5^z+1$ is divisible by $7,$ so it cannot yield a solution.

That finishes your solution, since it means that $x=y=1$ are the only solutions.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you exclude the cases z=6k+1 and 6k+5. I see how even exponents are excluded. But how these exponents are excluded??

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos The other cases were already excluded by OP of $y>1.$